# How to change a reported speech into a direct speech, in Magic's song 'Rude'

Tags: reported-speech, interpretation

In the words of Magic's song "Rude" there is a following sentench.

You say I'll never get your blessing 'til the day I die.

Which will be correct, if this sentence is put into direct speech?
(a) You say, "You'll never get my blessing until the day I die."
(b) You say, "You'll never get my blessing until the day you die."

Answer (score 2):

The first 'I' becomes 'you', so the second 'I' does as well, so "You'll never get my blessing until the day you die".

"You'll never get my blessing until the day I die" would become "You say I'll never get your blessing until the day *you* die".

Either way, I'll never get your blessing while we are both alive.